# Best way to call Clojure function with named/default args from Java

Tags: java, clojure

When calling a Clojure function from Java, what's the best way to specify named arguments to the function?

I have the following function:

```
(defn myFn [a b & {:keys [c d] :or {c 1 d 2}}]
   ; do something
   )
```

And I currently call it from Java with lines like this:

```
IFn myFn = Clojure.var("my.namespace", "myFn");
myFn.invoke(5, 6, Clojure.read(":c"), 7, Clojure.read(":d"), 8);
```

I find the `Clojure.read...` parts of the above statement verbose.  Is there a simpler way to make this call?

Comment: Why don't you use a function with arity 4?

Comment: Because the arguments are optional.  I also call the same function without c and d.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not about how to pass named argument, but how to create keywords in Java code:

```
import clojure.lang.Keyword;
// others omitted...
myFn.invoke(5, 6, Keyword.find("c"), 7, Keyword.find("d"), 8);
```

`Clojure.read` would be considered too cumbersome for the task and too dangerous as it can read in any code.

Comment: You seem to have a typo: invokde should be invoke.

Comment: This is still verbose.  Is there anything shorter?  Or is there a better way to design this interface between clojure and Java?  Like using clojure prototypes or multi-methods?

Comment: @Jason Thanks, fixed. Regarding the further question, I don't see any *shorter/better* ways than this method invocation with arguments prepared. Not much redundancy here to be removed.

Comment: Hmmm... I feel an unsettling dissatisfaction with this answer. I suppose if I factored out the `Keyword.find("c")` and "d" bits into constants then they can be reused and the call to `invoke` will be shorter. So I accept your answer, but part of me is still waiting for something better :-)